# Why does this program not send information to terminal?

Tags: python

I have this pretty basic *python* program but for some reason it is not working as needed

```
while True : print(Buy Now)
```

this should continue sending hello world to me terminal but is not

help please i am new coder.

Comment: It should be failing with a syntax error. You need quotes around `Buy Now`

Comment: wait no syntacks err

Comment: python not install?

Comment: Do you not have python installed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write like followings. Because statements in the `print` needs double or single quote.

```
while True : 
    print("Buy Now")
```

or

```
while True : 
    print('Buy Now')
```